# What does this notation mean where the dot appears before nabla?

Tags: notation, vector-fields

I am reading [chapter 38 of GPU Gems](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch38.html) and the author uses this notation where the dot appears before nabla (sec 38.2.1, eq 1, first term on the right side).

$-(\mathbf u \cdot \nabla)\mathbf u$

The book explains that nabla followed by dot means divergence but they've reversed the order in there. Is it "gradient of u"?

Answer (score 2):

$$(\mathbf u \cdot \nabla)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

Where $u_i$ is the $i$th component of $\mathbf u$ and $n$ is the number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for answeinr, can you explain what d/dxi means here?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is the partial derivative with respect to the $i$th coordinate. You can think of the expression I wrote in my answer as a directional derivative. It is the rate of change along the direction $\mathbf u$. It is not a gradient.

Answer (score 2):

This is one term in the famous [Navier-Stokes equations](https://www.britannica.com/science/Navier-Stokes-equation).

In your 2D context, the boldface symbol $\mathbf{u}=(u,v)$ is a vector; the operator $\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla$ is simply $u\partial_1+v\partial_2$. Imagine you do inner product symbolically. And the vector
$$
(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{u}=(u\partial_1u+v\partial_2u,u\partial_1v+v\partial_2v).
$$

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. From reading that link, it seems like this basically means "gradient of u dot-product with u", is that accurate?